# Prevent UI from freezing when Downloading file/files

Tags: c#

I've been through and through the search results of this website but cant seem to find what im looking for, And the only close thread that I found never got answered. Im trying to prevent my UI from freezing when downloading files but Id like everything to work on Form Load instead of a button click or something else. Heres the code Im running with right now:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Show();
            if (!IsConnectedToInternet) //user is not connected to internet
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not connected to internet!\n Please check your connection.", settings.cheatname);
            }
            else //user is connected to internet
            {
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (senderX, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
                var newversion = client.DownloadString(settings.versiontxt);
                var newversionparsed = int.Parse(newversion);
                if (settings.version < newversionparsed) 
                {
                 
                    var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
                    var stringChars = new char[8];
                    var random = new Random();
                    for (int i = 0; i < stringChars.Length; i++)
                    {
                        stringChars[i] = chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];
                    }
                    var finalString = new String(stringChars);

                    Stream[] sounds = new Stream[] {
    _2B.Properties.Resources.russian,
    _2B.Properties.Resources.byebye
};
                    Stream sound = sounds[random.Next(sounds.Length)];
                    SoundPlayer audio = new SoundPlayer(sound);
                    audio.Play();
                    //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2300); //<=== Testing wait theory.
                    // Downloading the new version
                    WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
                    myWebClient.DownloadFile(settings.loaderexe, Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/" + finalString + ".exe");
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/" + finalString + ".exe");
                    Application.Exit();
                        string batchCommands = string.Empty;
                        string exeFileName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase.Replace("file:///", string.Empty).Replace("/", "\\");
                }
                else
                {
                    Login nextForm = new Login();
                    this.Hide();
                    nextForm.ShowDialog();
                    this.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I know I have to use a backgroundworker but I cant seem to get it to work im not very smart when it comes to splitting threads and stuff so the usage of a backgroundworker to me is completely new. I'd like to learn but I wanna know how it SHOULD be so I can note that for future reference. Any help would be appreciated and posted code examples on how to fix or make what I need to do possible would be great.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Thread/ThreadPool/Task to run your download function in another thread, so the UI won't freeze.

And if your function need to update the UI, you need to use `Control.Invoke` method to make thread-safe UI update.

You can check this [UI update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-do-i-update-the-gui-from-another-thread) to solve the problem.

And I recommend to use this code below :

```
   this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        textBox1.Text = newversion;  //If need to update the UI
        textBox1.Visible = false;
    });
```

And your code in Form1_Load would be like

```
Task.Run(() => //Run the method in another thread to prevent freezing UI
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            var newversion = client.DownloadString("someurl"); //time consuming method

            //other code

            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                txtClass.Text = newversion;  //If need to update the UI
            });

            //other code
        });
```

**Edit:** It would be better in the Form_Shown event, then you can see the form :) That's adding to the illusion that it's hanging/freezing.

**Edit:** I've gone ahead and added what you provided and adapted to fit the progressbar, Thanks to both of you the UI doesnt freeze and I can actually see it. HOWEVER the progressbar isnt actually synced with the download, How would I be able to sync it with the download? Heres the code now:

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Task.Run(() => //Run the method in another thread to prevent freezing UI
            {
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (senderX, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
                var newversion = client.DownloadString(settings.versiontxt);
                var newversionparsed = int.Parse(newversion);

                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    bunifuCircleProgressbar1.Value =+ 1;  //If need to update the UI
                });

                if (settings.version < newversionparsed)
                {

                    var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
                    var stringChars = new char[8];
                    var random = new Random();
                    for (int i = 0; i < stringChars.Length; i++)
                    {
                        stringChars[i] = chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];
                    }
                    var finalString = new String(stringChars);

                    Stream[] sounds = new Stream[] {
    _2B.Properties.Resources.russian,
    _2B.Properties.Resources.byebye
};
                    Stream sound = sounds[random.Next(sounds.Length)];
                    SoundPlayer audio = new SoundPlayer(sound);
                    audio.Play();
                    //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2300); //<=== Testing wait theory.
                    // Downloading the new version
                    WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
                    myWebClient.DownloadFile(settings.loaderexe, Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/" + finalString + ".exe");
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/" + finalString + ".exe");
                    Application.Exit();
                    string batchCommands = string.Empty;
                    string exeFileName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase.Replace("file:///", string.Empty).Replace("/", "\\");
                }
                else
                {
                    Login nextForm = new Login();
                    this.Hide();
                    nextForm.ShowDialog();
                    this.Close();
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: So I want to update a progressbar I have which is this ```bunifuCircleProgressbar1.Value += 1;``` Could I replace the textbox.text and the textbox stuff to adapt to the progress bar?

Comment: @Russianfkr Yes, any control you want to update, you can put in that ‘’this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {})’ method.